# Is there anyway you can track the call history to someone who keeps on cancelling your calls?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to track the call history to someone who keeps on canceling your calls? I like to see how many times they've been called already. I'm using a iPhone 5.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

- Open the Phone app and tap Recents.
- Tap the "i" icon next to the desired number.
- A list of calls will appear with information about them.

If the call was outbound and displays no duration, it would be reasonable to assume that they didn't answer.

Comment: Thank you for this @bassplayer7. My phone only stores about a month history, would you know if there's anyway you can obtain more history?